# How convert constant float value to 4 bytes hex constant value in compile time?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, compile-time-constant

How convert constant float value to hex in compile time?

In runtime i do in this way:

```
int main()
{
    union float_to_int
    {
        float                           float_;
        int                             int_;
    };

    printf("43.2 in hex: 0x%X.\n", float_to_int{ 43.2f }.int_);

    return 0;
}
```

How to do this in compile time? I'm completely lost

Comment: Please note that your code is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Broadly speaking... you don't. Any mechanism you might use to accomplish this will invoke UB (the one you posted certainly does), and anything UB in compile-time code is explicitly defined to be ill-formed.

Well, until C++20 which will [add `std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast), a function that can convert trivially copyable types by doing the equivalent of bytewise copies between them. It is defined as `constexpr` (so long as the source and destination types are appropriate for that action), so you can do these conversions at compile-time.

Comment: And how is that implemented? Type punning?

Comment: @Red.Wave: Type punning is when you use a piece of memory as two different objects. `bit_cast` returns a *new object*, a prvalue which has no memory overlap with the given object. Also, the standard library runs on fiat; it does what it does because the standard says it does. It doesn't need to be something that you could implement yourself.

Comment: library used to be distinct from keywords. At least in the sense that library would be implemented inside the language(with the exception of ‘std::type_info‘). Looks like starting with ‘std:: initializer_list‘ everythings finds its way in the library rather than keyword set. If we don't stop right now, 'namespace std' becomes insanely populated with a jungle of magic types. And about punning, what prevents a function from returning a copy of punned object?(so the implementation be type_punning deep down, but returned by value)

Comment: @Red.Wave: "*with the exception of ‘std::type_info‘*" So you admit that there is *precedent*, and therefore the library was never really "distinct from keywords." "*what prevents a function from returning a copy of punned object?*" That doesn't make sense. You don't pun an object per-se; you pun a *memory address*. Returning a copy of the object representation of an object is different from punning the object.